# size() Vs empty() in vector - why empty() is preferred?

Tags: c++, stl, size

While debugging something, I saw the STL vector::empty() implementation:

```
bool empty() const
        {return (size() == 0); }
```

I believe, whenever we are probing the emptiness of vector it is always recommended to use empty over size(). But seeing that implementation, I am wondering, what is the benefit of doing so? Instead, there is a function call overhead in calling empty as it internally calls size()==0.

I thought empty() may be helpful in case of list as size() doesn't guarantees the constant time in list. To verify my assumption, I checked the list implementation and surprisingly, found the same implementation in list as well,

```
return (size() == 0);
```

I am bit confused now. If empty internally uses size() then why should we prefer empty over size() ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You would need to write the condition out everytime you use `size()`. It's convenient to use `empty()`. This is of course, provided you don't switch containers. As others have pointed out, it is upto the implementation to use `size()` in `empty()` or not. However, the standard does guarantee that: `empty()` is a constant-time operation for all
standard containers.

Comment: is that the only difference ? a convenient factor

Comment: aJ: No, not just for convenience. Read the two other comments (including mine).

Comment: Agreed. With respect to client code, yes, writing generic code using empty makes sense. I was bit bemused about my STL internal impl of using  size inside empty.

Comment: @aJ: This is one of the items in Scott Meyers, Effective STL.

Comment: Okay, I will check that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @dirkgently, Thanks for the excellent reference. I can upvote only once:).

Comment: @dirkgently no need to write the condition in full: `if (v.size())` or `if (! v.size())`

Comment: @dirkgently I know this is a very old post, but still important. Could you please point to the standard where this guarantee is stated.

Answer (score 52):

Because if you switch from std::vector to std::list or other container, it may be different.

For example some implementations of `std::list::size` take `O(n)` and not `O(1)`.

Comment: Indeed. I'd like to add that this is useful when writing generic code and you don't know which container is actually being used.

Comment: That is exactly the reason, `size()` should be a constant time operation but the standard allows the implementor to have a non-constant time implementation. In the other hand, `empty()` *must* be a constant time operation in *all* implementations.

Comment: Of course, if you decide to switch from `std::vector` to something like `std::list` you will have a lot bigger problems. Like totally different iterator invalidation rules.

Comment: This answer is correct in C++03. In C++11 `size` must be constant time.

Comment: @BillyONeal Right. So choosing b/w `container.size() > 0` vs `!container.empty()` is now a matter of style then?  I personally prefer the latter since it's more explicit about the intention/readability.

Answer (score 12):

Well, as you say, that's just an implementation detail. `std::list` can be implemented either with a stored size (constant-time `size()` but linear-time `splice()`), or without (constant-time `splice()` but linear-time `size()`). By choosing to use `empty()`, you avoid betting on an implementation detail, when you don't need to know the size.

Answer (score 8):

1st, using a function called `empty()` when you want to know if something is empty makes code more readable, and means you don't have to worry about implementation details. It also means that your code can more easily be adapted to other types of containers, with other characteristics.

2nd, that's just one STL implementation.
My GNU C++ one looks like this:

```
bool
empty() const
{ return begin() == end(); }
```

This will eventually result in a pointer comparison, while using size() would result in a subtraction (in this implementation).

3rd, it's not very likely to incur the overhead of an extra function call, since the `empty()`-function is probably inlined (in both of the implementations).

Answer (score 7):

Following the standard, empty() should be preferred as it has constant time complexity regardless of the container type.

In C++03 standard, chapter 23.1, table 65: Container Requirements

```
Operation:   empty()
Return_type: convertible to bool
Semantics:   equivalent to size()==0
Complexity:  constant
```

It seems as if in your STL implementation, they took the semantics as the real implementation ignoring the complexity requirements, or size() is constant time in the implementation (stored field).

If size() is not constant time, contact your vendor about std::list<>::empty() not fulfilling the standard container requirements.

Comment: I don't think that there is any hard evidence that his STL implementation is non-conformant. The standard even says that size() should be constant time for all containers, including list.

Comment: I edited the last part of the post, but forgot to update the top part.

Comment: i'm not sure, but the sgi STL site describes empty() as having amorized constant time complexity. whereas the c++ standard indeed describes it as having constant time complexity. therefor i think it's important to not mix "STL" and "Standard C++ Library". neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: or if one says STL one should say one means STandardc++Library instead of StandardTemplateLibrary . I find it often mixed :)

Comment: if you look in my answers, i never say STL when i mean the standard c++ library, because it only causes confusion. e.g why should one not include std::cout into the STL (Standardc++Library)? so if someone says STL and includes coutinto it, other people may not include it. and then confusion arises:)

Comment: I have always read about the STL being the Standard Template Library, and I often believed it to be the part of the Standard C++ Library that regards templates. This has been the first time I heard someone making such a different, but indeed the StandardC++ does not mention STL ever.

Comment: STL is the Standard Template Library, most of it was adopted by the 1998 C++ standard, and some of its techniques were later applied to other components such as iostreams and strings.  Today, some people incorrectly refer to the whole C++ Standard Library or to its full complement of templates as "the STL". http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/95/HPL-95-11.html http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

Answer (score 5):

empty() has O(1) implementations for ALL container classes. size() can only provide O(n) implementations for some containers; this is why empty() is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the reasons given above, it's also arguably clearer than foo.size() == 0 and/or !foo.size()

Comment: Oor arguably not. After years of using it, when glancing at code I still sometimes get the impression that alist.empty() is emptying the list. I think it should be called is_empty() (like is_open() in iostreams)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the readability point, which is very valid, what you experienced is simply the artifacts of one particular implementation, not the only possible one.

That is, there is no reason or requirement that empty() be implemented in terms of size() in both the vector and list case, or in deed any other container. If there are better performing alternatives, they should be used, unless the author(s) of the library are incompetent, or more reasonably, lazy.

As for the list and the O(1)-ness of size(), or the lack thereof, you should take into account that list may implement either size() as O(1) or splice(), but not both (thinking about the reason is an interesting exercise.) So in your case, the library you inspected may have implemented size() as O(1) (in which case splice() would be O(n)) and therefore could implement empty() in terms of size() without sacrificing performance, otherwise, that would be a really bad library.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use use empty() than size() because, each container might implement empty() implementation in a different way to get the constant time operation.

example:

vector implements as : 
            bool empty() const
        {   // test if sequence is empty
        return (size() == 0);
        }

list implements as :

```
        bool empty() const
    {   // test if sequence is empty
    return (_Mysize == 0);
    }
```