# How to check if hidl_vec is empty?

Tags: android, c++, googlemock, hal, hidl

In Android, we can use [HIDL data types](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-cpp/types#vect) in lieu of normal C++ data types. Their functionality remains mostly the same, and this proxy code is for behind-the-scenes serialization and IPC which HIDL takes care of.

Now when I try to check if a HIDL vector is empty, I get the error that `empty` is not a member of `hidl_vec`. How then can I check this? Some other functions that work on a normal vector work with `hidl_vec` such as `foo.size()`, `foo.begin()`, `foo.end()` but I prefer to not use the size check for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863282/checking-whether-a-vector-is-empty) reason.

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
using ::android::hardware::hidl_vec;
using ::android::hardware::hidl_string;

hidl_vec<hidl_string> foo;

ASSERT_FALSE(foo.empty());
```

Throws the error:

> error: no member named 'empty' in 'android::hardware::hidl_vecandroid::hardware::hidl_string'
> ASSERT_FALSE(foo.empty());

Comment: I think I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796200/is-begin-end-for-any-empty-vector

Comment: That would be a question to the hidl library documentation, but that seems non-existent.

Comment: Btw, `vec.size() == 0` seems easier to process mentally than `vec.begin() == vec.end()`. So if `empty()` doesn't exist, I'd stick with `size()`.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense, thanks.